# Pass LINQ query to method to select dynamically form collection

Tags: c#, linq, expression, func

I already looked up on the question on SO, but couldn't find a solution for my problem.

In my program is a class whose sole reason is selecting from a collection of data passed to it via constructor.
What I need to to is pass a LINQ query to the selecting method to select from said data. However I have no luck solving my problem.
Here is the code:

```
public class ServiceClient<TInput>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<TInput> data;

    public ServiceClient(IEnumerable<TInput> dataInput)
    {
        this.data = dataInput;
    }

    public TResult Send<TResult>(Func<IEnumerable<TInput>, TResult> selector)
    {
        var selectedData = this.data.Select(selector); // How to do the selection here???

        // ...
    }
}
```

The class is called this way:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var persons = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Id = 0, FamilyId = 0 },
        new Person { Id = 1, FamilyId = 0 },
        new Person { Id = 2, FamilyId = 1 }
    };

    var func = new Func<IEnumerable<Person>, Person>(Target);

    var client = new ServiceClient<Person>(persons);

    client.Send(func);
}

private static Person Target(IEnumerable<Person> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
var selectedData = this.data.Select(selector);
```

with:

```
var selectedData = selector(this.data);
```

It should be enough.
`selector` is delegate that acceps collection and returns single element, so you need invoke `selector` delegate with `data` argument.

If you would like to use `Select` like `this.data.Select(..)` your `selector` delegate should rather be like `Func<TInput, TResult>` - delegate that projects one element into another.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Seems I have to get more familiar with funcs any good recommendation on that topic?

Comment: I recommend to you nice book: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft%C2%AE-PRO-Developer-Paolo-Pialorsi/dp/0735624003 I have read it and found very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Send that way:

```
public TResult Send<TResult>(Func<IEnumerable<TInput>, TResult> selector)
{
     return selector(data);
}
```